# SQLite or Parse for android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, parse-platform, database-connection

I am an amateur app developer. I have developed many android apps but for offline use only. Now I'd like to make an online app. The users should login with Facebook account and I handled that. The problem is that I want to save some data like the user Facebook friend-list and some other stuff. I knew that there are 2 ways to solve such problem the first one is using Parse and the second one is using the SQL-lite so which of them should I use?

Comment: Sqlite is local while parse is remote. You need to determine which solution suites your architecture.

Comment: It should also be noted that questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are **off-topic** for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @MuhammadBabar what do you think best suites my app? the main idea of the app is that you choose some people from your friend-list and ask them a question and they answer. it is something like the TriviaCrack game. should i use local or remote storage?

Comment: @EdGeorge i am already not asking about any of what you mentioned :)

Comment: You are asking us to _recommend_ you a tool - either SQLite or Parse. For that reason, this is off-topic

Comment: You should go for Remote i.e Parse, MySQL etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the Parse database is more suitable in this case, because you will be able to sync the data automatically, when you store it in the cloud

Comment: This should probably be a comment - Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better.

Comment: can't i use SQLite to sync?

Comment: No, I think that with SQLite your data is only on the device (if I am wrong, someone could correct me, but I think it's so)  and Parse.com is a database in the cloud, so when the users have internet access, they will have the synced data